# Publish Modules from a Java Project on Github and integrate into IntelliJ

Tags: programming-practices, github, modules, intellij

## What is the best practice to work with several Java modules from different GitHub sources using IntelliJ?

This might be an odd qeustion but I do not know what the standard workflow is to achieve what I have in mind.

### The current situation

I develop a Java project with IntelliJ and I manage my code with GitHub. The project is currently stored in a private repository on GitHuband it consists of several independent Maven modules. This is a sample structure:

[image: The project structure]

### The plan

Now I plan to publish only ModuleB on a public repository on GitHub. I want to share only this module and allow others to use it. What is the best practice so that I can develop Module B further within my project and all changes get published in the public repository? I do not know how to do this in IntelliJ. I am insecure about the workflow here or is there another pattern which I could follow to achieve this?

### Idea

I think I could export ModuleB, import it as a separate public repository into GitHub and then send pull requests when I make changes. But how do I do this with IntelliJ? How can I fork the public repository into my existing project, which is itself shared in a privare repository? Can I nest GitHub projects? Is this a good idea after all? Please let me know if my question is clear.

### Further clarification

I know that I can import several "modules" in IntelliJ, but this is a different thing, isn't it? An IntelliJ module is the same as an Eclipse project, which is an independent entity. I think I could solve the problem with this approach, but then I would have to commit the overall project seperately. Could this be solved more elegantly with  [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) perhaps?

## Proposed Solutions

My created a new GitHub repository for ModuleB and uploaded the source code to it. This module is now set as public and independent from the main project.

### Use IntelliJ import Module

Instead of trying to integrate the "external" repository directly into my current project, I cloned the ModuleB repository to a different directory. Then I imported the said folder as a new module in IntelliJ.
[image]

IntelliJ then asks if there sould be a dependency between the newly added ModuleB. Unfortunately this only adds an entry into the .iml file

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="Submodule" />
```

and not into the pom.xml file. So this information where to obtain the source for the module is only available in IntelliJ. How could this problem be addressed? I only tried it with a toy project so far, but if someone wants to import the whole project into Eclipse for instance, this might cause a problem. How could I reference the other GitHub repository in a useful way?

Comment: Can IntelliJ allow projects to rely on other projects?

Comment: We have to be careful with the terminology which is different in various IDEs I am afraid. For instance an eclipse project is an IntelliJ Module. I am talking of software modules, which do have a hierarchy. I can import several modules into Intelli J, but this creates two independent things, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a software tool, however it is too old to migrate to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution: Git Subtrees

After fidelling around with submodules, I found that git subtrees allow me to achieve what I wanted. I mainly used [this page](https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844) to learn about subtrees and followed the following procedure in order to integrate a submodule (submodule-repo.git) into the parent repository (parent.git)

```
# Start at the root of the parent repository. Add a new remote repository to the  parent. 
# Add a new remote repository location called Submodule-Subtree
git remote add Submodule-Subtree https://github.com/yourname/submodule-repo.git

# Check that the new remote location is there
git remote -v

# Now add the newly added remote location of the submodule to the parent
# by specifying a folder name where you want the submodule to be stored locally.
git subtree add --prefix=NewSubModule/ Submodule-Subtree master

# Save to the parent master
git push origin master

# make changes in the new module
cd NewSubModule/
touch ThisIsANewFile.txt
git add .

# Commit to the parent
commit -m "we added a new file in the submodule from the parent repository"
git push origin master


# So far the changes the changes are only visible in the parent repository, 
# but not in the original location. To share your changes with the original 
# submodule-repo.git, you need this command:
git subtree push --prefix=NewSubModule/ Submodule-Subtree master

# You also need to update the submodule-repository manually
# git subtree pull —prefix=NewSubModule/ Submodule-Subtree master
```

As a next step you can import this folder as a module via the File | Import Module | Existing Sources.

The honest background is that comming from a SVN and Eclipse world, I need to learn the terminology more precisely and get used to the new concepts. I found the [Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) very useful.